# Save and Retrieve KeyPair in AndroidKeystore

Tags: android, rsa, android-keystore

I need to generate a RSA 2048 Keypair, then save it, and recover it if it exists.

At this moment, I have this:

```
SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
RSAKeyGenParameterSpec spec = new RSAKeyGenParameterSpec(keySize, RSAKeyGenParameterSpec.F4);
KeyPairGenerator generator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA", "SC");
generator.initialize(spec, random);
return generator.generateKeyPair();
```

This works perfect, but now I tried to save and take it from Android Keystore, but I'm not achieving it. I tryed:

```
String alias = "TESTINGKEY";
KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
keyStore.load(null);
if (!keyStore.containsAlias(alias)) {
    SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
    RSAKeyGenParameterSpec spec = new RSAKeyGenParameterSpec(keySize, RSAKeyGenParameterSpec.F4);
    KeyPairGenerator generator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA", "SC");
    generator.initialize(spec, random);
    return generator.generateKeyPair();
} else {
    Key key = keyStore.getKey(alias, null);
    if (key instanceof PrivateKey) {
        Certificate cert = keyStore.getCertificate(alias);
        return new KeyPair(cert.getPublicKey(), (PrivateKey) key);
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

But is not working right, because at the second run of the app, the keystore don't contains the Keypair.

In https://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore.html?hl=es I saw that the `KeyGenParameterSpec`, the builder have a "alias" value, but int the `RSAKeyGenParameterSpec` don't.

How can I save it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

With AndroidKeyStore is needed to use `KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder` to generate the keys. Also use `AndroidKeyStore` instead of `SC`. You can use the following code

**Generate the keys (Android>=23)**

```
KeyPairGenerator kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance(
                KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_RSA, "AndroidKeyStore");

kpg.initialize(new KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(
                alias,
                KeyProperties.PURPOSE_SIGN | KeyProperties.PURPOSE_VERIFY)
                .setDigests(KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA256, KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA512)
                .setKeySize(keySize)
                .build());

KeyPair keyPair = kpg.generateKeyPair();
```

**Load the keys**

```
KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore");
keyStore.load(null);
KeyStore.Entry entry = keyStore.getEntry(alias, null);
PrivateKey privateKey = ((KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry) entry).getPrivateKey();
PublicKey publicKey = keyStore.getCertificate(alias).getPublicKey();
```

Comment: I tried what you post @pedrofb but, now, when I try to use the keypair.getPrivateKey().getEncoded(), launch a nullPointerException, because this getEnconded() has "nothing" inside.

Comment: The key material of keys stored in the Android Keystore is not accessible. You can use the keys but you can not extract them. It is a security restriction

Comment: @Shudy is my answer clear? If you need to extract the content of the private key you can't use `AndroidKeyStore`, but you can use it perfectly, and it is the recommend to way to keep it secure. Extracting a private key to store in a file means you would need additional security measures

Comment: Yes, yes. But the problem I have know with it, is that I need to send to a server my Public Key, (in string format), so when I tried to get the encode of public, to convert to string, is null.

Comment: I was referring to the privateKey. The public key raw data is accesible using `byte publickey[] = keyStore.getCertificate(alias).getPublicKey().getEncoded();`. You will need to convert it to base64 to send it to server as String

Comment: aaaahhh1!!!!! Perfect then! I just tryed with private one, and I supposed that will hapen with public to. I'll try again. ! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Shudy, Could you check it?

Comment: Does `kpg.generateKeyPair()` also store such generated keys to the `"AndroidKeyStore"` under the `alias` name, or the keys need to be stored by another method? If so, how? Please advise.

Comment: @Ωmega, the keys are generated inside "AndroidKeyStore" (even using hardware support if exists) and can be recovered (private key can not be extracted) using `alias`

Comment: @Ωmega, `kpg.generateKeyPair();` creates a new key pair, public and private, using a random number generator, and internally it stores the keys into the keystore linked to the provided alias. You must call this method to generate the key pair the first time

Comment: What is not working? I suggest to post a new question with the details

Answer (score 0):

additional to answer **pedrofb** for **SDK <= 22** you can use `KeyPairGeneratorSpec` instead of `KeyGenParameterSpec`

> Info:
>   https://developer.android.com/reference/android/security/KeyPairGeneratorSpec.html