# Android KeyStore not saving RSA key

Tags: java, android, rsa, android-keystore

I am using the android keystore api to store an RSA key pair.

When I run my android in debug mode it shows that the keypair and certificate bytes have been stored in the keystore but when I reload the debugger and try to retrieve the key, the keystore appears to be empty.

I want to be able to retrieve the key by alias. My code below shows how the keypair is created and stored.

```
    public RSA(char[] password) throws Exception {
    KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
    ks.load(null);
    Enumeration<String> aliases = ks.aliases();
    if(!aliases.hasMoreElements())
    {
        mCurrentCertificate = generateCert();
        //Store the new keypair
        FileInputStream fs = null;
        ks.load(fs, password);

        KeyStore.ProtectionParameter protParam =
                new KeyStore.PasswordProtection(password);

        java.security.cert.Certificate[] myCert =
                new java.security.cert.Certificate[] { (java.security.cert.Certificate) mCurrentCertificate};

        KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry pkEntry =
                new KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry(mCurrentRSAKeyPair.getPrivate(),
                        myCert);

        ks.setEntry("MyKey2", pkEntry, protParam);

        for(int i = 0; i < ks.size(); i++)
        {
            //MyKey is the previous key stored, MyKey2 is the next one
            System.out.println(ks.getCertificate("MyKey"));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your code you can create a keystore in the file system (it is missing `ks.store(fileOutputStream, password);`, but [Android Keystore System](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore.html) has a specific API to generate and use the keys

In this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42111319/6371459) you have an example to generate and load an RSA key